# Java server faces link doesn't work inside loop

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I have this simple code in facelets "numbers.xhtml":

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
  <body>
    <h1>Numbers page</h1>
  <table>
    <c:forEach var="number" items="#{numbers}">
    <tr>
        <td>
          <h:form>
          <h:commandLink action="#{numbers.showNumber}" value="#{number.number}" />
          </h:form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

In "showNumber" method I just return string "number" which is mapped in faces-config.xml to "number.xhtml" but it always opens "numbers.xhtml" page.

I even tried with "ui:repeat" tag but same results. If I put "h:commandLink" outside loop it works.

You have simple test case [here](https://bitbucket.org/XooR/test_facelets/get/3fed0cb6994c.zip). It is maven project and you need just to execute "./run_jetty.sh" to run simple jetty server.

Comment: I'm confused here, what is the type of `numbers`? `forEach` usually takes a Collection so does this type you are passing in actually have a `getShowNumber()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saw the src you attached, I think you need a getter method: `getShowNumber()` in your `Numbers` class. You might want to rename `public static String showNumber` to `public static String getShowNumber`.

Comment: Yes, but as the Java bean spec says (and as mentioned in your comment), to call `x.showNumber` you need to have `getShowNumber()` in your class.